# Can Microsoft Purview classify a column containing XML or JSON data through scan?

Tags: azure-purview

I want to scan my Location database which is present in Azure SQL database. While scanning with system classification rules, it identifies classification for Cities, Countries, etc.

If these fields are present in a column "Demography" (datatype=varchar(max)) having values like
{"City": "California", "Country": "United States"}, will this column be classified after scanning the data source?

Added scan and classification for Azure SQL database

Comment: Yes, Purview should be able to classify JSON values within a column. Try this data pattern ^\\{.*\\}$ when creating your regular expression which should match any string within curly braces i.e the structure of a JSON object. Incase you need to read more on how to create a custom classification please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/create-a-custom-classification-and-classification-rule#custom-classification-rules